# Android device: prevent shutdown when charging and wake-lock active

Tags: android

Again I find myself at very limit of my Android knowledge (apologies in advance if this request isn't appropriate here)

Created a continuous running App on Android 8.1+ based on the excellent GitHub "stay-awake-app" example.  In terms of functionality, it works perfectly as designed including sending sms alerts

Background: migrating Windows App running on Intel Nucs/Win10 because they seldom reboot reliably after a Windows update, are power hungry and need UPS

Key requirement: the Android devices, as with the Nucs, can be left powered on, running and unattended for months on end

Therefore, battery state isn't terribly important other than being a handy built-in UPS in a power outage

Also found I can manipulate Android device settings using adb, for example sms thresholds e.g. ("put" to change):

```
C:\adb\platform-tools>adb shell
VFD620:/ $ settings get global sms_outgoing_check_max_count
500
VFD620:/ $ settings get global sms_outgoing_check_interval_ms
1800000
VFD620:/ $
```

THE PROBLEM: After about 10 days or so (280hrs, 100k cycles) I discover the Android Go devices have just switched themselves off..! Further, these devices refuse to respond to notifications when the app isn't running, whereas Samsung/Nokia devices receive notifications fine without the app running and even being switched on again.

THE WORKAROUND: Manually switch it back on again. Starts/Runs fine, as if nothing had ever happened.

THE QUESTION: Is there some obscure setting somewhere in Android that can tell it not to switch off... like ever..?

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be cheap, telco badged phones that don't have any real staying power, especially these two (both Android supported devices);

VFD620 - Smart_N9_Lite, System on Chip - Mediatek MT6739WA

VFD720 - Vodafone Smart N9, System on Chip - Mediatek MT6739WA

More expensive branded devices (e.g. Nokia, Samsung) just seem to work better

MORAL: Always invest in good kit..!